# Changing position of CAShapeLayer using an animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cashapelayer

I have a `UITextField` centered in my viewcontroller. I'm using a `CAShapeLayer` underneath the textfield that grows in width as text is typed in the textfield. Once the user presses enter, a `UITableView` that is hidden at the bottom of the view slides up. I'm able to get the tableview and textfield to slide up by changing their constraints.

```
func moveUp(){

    searchBarTopConstraint.constant = 0
    tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {

        self.view.layoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the `CAShapeLayer` to slide up with the textfield. I tried creating a function that moves the line and putting it in a UIView animation with a completion handler, but the line will either move up after the animation or before.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.00, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        self.moveLine()

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

//            self.moveLine()

    })
```

The y position of the line is determined by the textfields position (this is a concise version of the moveLine()):

```
    let y = searchField.frame.origin.y + searchField.frame.size.height + 6
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x:x1, y:y))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:x2, y:y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. If moving views via constraints, you call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block, not `layoutSubviews()`

   As the [`layoutSubviews()` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) says:

   > You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the [`setNeedsLayout()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout) method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the [`layoutIfNeeded()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) method.

   In your case, put `layoutIfNeeded()` inside your `animate` closure, not `layoutSubviews()`.
2. Note that when you do this properly, this moves the view in which you have the `CAShapeLayer`, not moving the `CAShapeLayer` itself. So, if you have a shape layer that you want to move, you'd put that shape layer with a view with the constraints, and then move the view with the above `layoutIfNeeded()` call.

   Theoretically, you actually can animate the moving of a `CAShapeLayer` within a view using `CABasicAnimation`:

   ```
   let position = CGPoint(...)                          // the new origin of the CAShapeLayer within its view

   let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
   animation.fromValue = shapeLayer.position            // animate from current position ...
   animation.toValue = position                         // ... to whereever the new position is
   animation.duration = 2
   shapeLayer.position = position                       // set the shape's final position to be the new position so when the animation is done, it's at its new "home"
   shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)               // animate from `fromValue` to `toValue`
   ```

   Personally, I think it's a little confusing to move shape layers within a view, and I prefer to put the shape layer within its own view, add that view within your view hierarchy with the associated constraints, and then animate that view's constraints. It makes debugging of views with the Xcode view debugger easier, IMHO.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you suggesting creating a view for the shape layer and applying constraints to the view?

Comment: If you haven't already, yes. Constraints are between views, not layers. So if you animate via constraints, you need to animate the view that has the `CAShapeLayer`. And if that `CAShapeLayer` is a layer of a view that you don't want to move, you can't move the shape layer within that view with constraints. But if you put that `CAShapeLayer` on its own view, add that as a subview within your broader view hierarchy, then you can animate the movement of the subview and its layers (e.g. the `CAShapeLayer`) go with it.

Comment: Makes sense. Since this is just a straight line, can't i just make a view and skip the shape layer?

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by "straight line". Is the shape a horizontal or vertical line that's moving around? Then, yes, you can render this "line" by making a very narrow view and giving that view a background color and move that around, bypassing the `CAShapeLayer` altogether. But if this "straight line" is a diagonal or might have other adornments like arrowheads, dashed pattern, etc., then I'd personally do it with a view with a `CAShapeLayer` within that. (If you have a diagonal line, you make a narrow view and rotating that, but that's starting to get too cute by half.)